# how to remove all element with a specific innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
function checkIfBlank() {
  let li = document.getElementsByClassName("li");
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  if (li[i].innerHTML === "hello") {
    li[i].parentElement.remove();
  }
  }
}
```

```html
<li>
    <span class="li">hi</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="li">hi</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="li">hi</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="li">hello</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="li">hello</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="li">hello</span>
</li>
```

i have this function that will remove parent element of the span that has innerHTML of "hello"

In this case, I expect the code to remove all elements with innerHTML of hello

but turns out it only removes one element when function is executed

can anybody help me on this? im not really good xD

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6vrn5ux4/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such purposes, it is safer to use `Array.from(element)`.

```js
function checkIfBlank() {
    let li = document.getElementsByClassName("li");
    Array.from(li).forEach(function (li_curr) {
        if (li_curr.innerHTML == "hello") {
            li_curr.parentElement.remove();
        }
    });
}

checkIfBlank();
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="li">hi</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="li">hi</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="li">hi</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="li">hello</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="li">hello</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="li">hello</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery solution:

```js
$('li:contains("hello")').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="li">hi</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="li">hi</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="li">hi</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="li">hello</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="li">hello</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="li">hello</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi thanks for answering, why is it better to use array.from?

Comment: @coder, Because the this it designed for similar tasks as yours. for {} loop performs the operation n times, and may not fall into the interval of n elements. I faced a similar problem myself. But you can quite use the jquery solution that the other respondent gave you. By the way, this answer can be shortened as - $('.li:contains("hello")').parent().remove(); or $('li:contains("hello")').remove();. I indicated this in my second solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery to remove li with match text i hope you will get your answer .

```js
$('li:contains("hello")')
 .next('span').remove().end()
 .remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <span class="li">hi</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="li">hi</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="li">hi</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="li">hello</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="li">hello</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="li">hello</span>
</li>
```

enjoy my code ;)

Comment: if you need any help then message me its glad for me to help you .

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive there aren't any that look like this:

```
<span class="li">
    Hello
</span>
```

Instead of this:

```
<span class="li">Hello</span>
```

First thing that came to mind for me was if there's any line-break or white-space then you will definitely need to run .trim() on that innerHTML string. However if that's not it, I'd suggest a bunch of console.log()'s in certain places to see how far it gets in the for loop.